# Preferred database for storing long word-meaning list in android

Tags: android

I want to make a dictionary app in android. What would be the preferred and efficient database for storing word-meanings list ? I am a novice programmer, any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Android has [builtin SQLite support](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) that you can use in your application. I see that there is a [sample project](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) called *Searchable Dictionary* that looks quite similar to what you are trying to achieve, so maybe you can use that as guide.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a mobile environment something quite small seems to be a better option.

use sqlite3 or xmlsimple java library.

http://simple.sourceforge.net/
http://www.sqlite.org/